# Playing random sound with Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, audio

Im planing on using this code to make random sounds play with an action, not exactly sure on how to name my sound files. Thanks for any help.

```
int randomNumber = arc4random() % 24 + 1;

NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sound%02d", randomNumber] ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer * soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];

[soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
[soundPlayer play];
```

Comment: Did you not write this code yourself?

Comment: No i searched "how to play random sound" just not sure how to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This attitude will not get your questions answered. I suggest you read the FAQ section.

Comment: I noticed you guys were not so quick to answer my question but were quick to jump down my throat about my inappropriate behavior.

Comment: I recommend changing your string format to %i.  %d looks for a double, not an int.

Comment: @CodaFi Uh... %d specifies a signed integer, not a double!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name them like this:

Sound01.mp3
Sound02.mp3
...
Sound24.mp3

Comment: Sound25.mp3 should not be exist, the max random number will be 24 through `arc4random() % 24 + 1`